# how to write 301 redirect by checking an special character from the url using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, 301-redirect

I have few urls contain some special characters like below

```
www.abc.com/archive/category/コレクション-帯-袋帯
www.abc.com/archive/category/お役立ち情報
```

I want to write .htaccess to handle this redirection.

I tried this way but its not working

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\コ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\お [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.asterdmhealthcare.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

How can i do this? Can someone please help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this redirection by writing a **RewriteRule** only.

```
RewriteRule ^.*コ.* https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^.*お.* https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

this lines did the work